# Djnago channels security

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I'm studying django channels and there's this problem: let's say I have a routing channel:

```py
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^ws/chat/(?P<id>[^/]+)/$', ChatConsumer),
]
```

It turns out, anyone who knows the channel number, can listen to messages going to this address. Maybe you can send data (for example, a token) sometime during the socket connection?

Comment: That's why you need `AuthMiddleWareStack` to wrap the urlpatterns.https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/authentication.html#django-authentication

Comment: @minglyu Thank you for the answer! I don't understand how I missed this moment in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

use a Auth middleware

example

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from myapp import consumers

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({

"websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
    URLRouter([
        url(r"^front(end)/$", consumers.AsyncChatConsumer),
    ])
),

})
```